# Native SIP INFO message (RFC 6086)

Tags: android, sip

Does the native SIP stack have the ability to send an INFO Method/Message ([RFC 6086](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6086))?

In the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/network/sip.html) it says it suports a full SIP stack including instant messageing that would normally be achieved with the INFO message, however I can't see a way to send an in-call (or out of call for that matter) INFO message with the documented interface.

Thanks, any and all help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

[SIMPLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMPLE) doesn't use INFO (though I suppose you could implement an IM protocol using INFO).  It uses SUBSCRIBE/NOTIFY (and PUBLISH) for presence and MESSAGE for instant messaging.

The documentation you refer to is way higher level - there's no ability to directly send or receive specific SIP messages.  In fact, while they mention instant messaging, the API's given only support audio calls.